# See all hot questions on one page

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

I would like to see *all* hot questions on one page, as opposed to multiple pages of 15/30/50 links as it is available now. This is because even with 2 pages by the time I'm done clicking through the interesting links and go to next page, some links have moved and I need to go back to the first page and see if I missed anything. Please fix this issue by letting me see all questions on one page. This will also save the site a few page requests.

Comment: You can't just, I dunno, open the next page in a new tab before clicking anything?

Comment: There is still a chance it will change between clicks. I could maybe write a userscript that would request the two pages twice in a row and compile it into a single page of links as a workaround, but it should be much easier for the SE dev team to just add "all" next to 15, 30 and 50.